# How can I know if the data was updated in mysql database or an error had occured

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I build a web site. my server side is written in node (express).
I use connection to mysql database for updating data.
The updating is done by calling to stored procedure.
the connection is:

```
connection.query("call update_user(?)",id,
        function(err, results)
        {
            connection.release();
        });
    }
});
```

I want to know what the result object contains.
when I log it:

```
console.log(result);
```

I get the output: "[Object object]".

It's not what I want.

so what are the properties of result object?

Comment: What if you use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`? Also is this `result` different from `results` in the code snippet you've posted?

Comment: Thanks, but I had a mistake: when I log: console.log(result); the output is [Object object] without Quotation marks. when I use console.dir the output is "[Object object]". what I want is to know what the properties of results are.

Comment: If that's the output, then it sounds like your `result` variable is holding the string literal `'[Object object]'` and not an actual object. How are you assigning `result`, `result = results[0]` or something else?

Comment: I tried to log results[0] and got undefined.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `update_user()` stored procedure?

Comment: of course not! It's in my mysql database. I thought I can get the results as I get in stored procedure that selects data. Can't I?

Comment: Well without knowing what `update_user()` is doing, if it's just making UPDATE/INSERT statements, you won't get any rows back, which is probably why there `results` is not defined would be my guess.

Comment: I think that if I don't get any rows back, the result of logging the results needs to be "undefined". am I not right?

Comment: Possibly not, since IIRC prepared statements work kind of like executing multiple statements in a query, there are several results in a single response. If you make a prepared statement that does a select that *should* return rows for example and you see none, then I would report it to the github issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has changed, but suddenly it work!
when I log the result, I get:

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
affectedRows: 1,
insertId: 0,
serverStatus: 2,
warningCount: 0,
message: '',
protocol41: true,
changedRows: 0 }
```

So I know if the data has changed.